# How does a zener diode regulate a voltage?

Tags: diodes

If the rule is with parallel circuits that the voltage is the same across all nodes eg:

How does a zener diode regulate a voltage?

After the current passes the Rs resistor and we calculate that voltage (let's say it's 4.5 volts), won't the voltage be the same for both nodes? Even if the zener diode is dropping voltage both nodes should have the same starting voltage of 4.5 volts after the Rs resistor?

When I mean nodes I am referring to the node 1 and node 2 (both drawn in red)

How does a zener diode act to reduce voltage at nodes 1 and 2?

The tutorial I am following, https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/diode/diode_7.html, is really poorly explained, with a  bunch of extraneous information.

[image]

Comment: 1 and 2 is the same location, electrically. I have no idea what you are asking here.

Comment: yeah, that is the thing that is confusing me. How does the zener diode control the voltage at steady level. If Rl pulls more current how does the zener diode keep the voltage the same?

Comment: It starts conducting at a specified voltage. Which has nothing to do with point 1 and 2, both will follow each other.

Comment: Okay, so the zener diode drops voltage, but how does that affect Rl? Does that get the lower voltage as well?

Comment: Who said that the zener drops voltage? The zener voltage is ostensibly constant when it's conducting. The only way the load can draw more current is by reducing its resistance - Ohm's law.

Comment: Are you simply asking how a zener diode works? RS and RL forms a voltage divider without the zener, but if the voltage ends up higher than what the zener is specified for, it will "burn away" the extra energy. So if you have calculated 4.5V without the zener, but the zener starts conducting at 4V, then you get Vz = 4V, simple as that.

Comment: okay, appreciate everyone's feedback. I'm a little confused. I thought that diodes do drop voltages like 0.7. I see the voltage divider but i'm having problems understanding how the diode is involved in it.

Comment: "I thought that diodes do drop voltages like 0.7..."  Pleas add this statement to your question, it illuminates your confusion.

Comment: That is a rectifier diode @Cameron

Answer (score 4):

From [the same tutorial where you found the circuit](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/diode/diode_7.html), you should also be able to find a plot of the diode voltage vs. current characteristics (shown below).

Normal silicon diodes drop around 0.7V in the *forward direction* (but that can vary).  Just about every diode will conduct at a higher voltage in the *reverse* direction.  The voltage at which that happens is called the "reverse breakdown voltage.  That reverse breakdown voltage depends on how the diode is made.

A Zener diode is purposely made to have a controlled reverse breakdown voltage, and to be able to be operated continuously in reverse breakdown.  So if you shove current through a Zener diode backwards, it should hold a fairly constant voltage.

[image]
<sub>(source: [electronics-tutorials.ws](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/diode/diode11.gif))</sub>

Comment: Thanks Tim, I understand how the diode works but the issue im not understanding is how th diode helps keep the voltage at a certain voltage when its in parallel

Comment: Does it work like this: The more current that RL pulls the less current the diode pulls; the less current that RL pulls the more current the diode pulls. Thus it stablizes the voltage by balancing these two things? As long as it has enougth voltage to reverse bias of course

Comment: Yes, that's it exactly.  And if you should ever pull enough current on the load that the  diode current drops to zero, it stops regulating.

Comment: @Cameron A possible problem to watch out for when designing this type of regulator - If the load will ever be removed (disconnected) then all the current that was previously flowing in the load will be redirected through the zener and so if the load will ever be disconnected  ensure that the power rating of the zener is sufficient for sinking all the current being sourced by the resistor to avoid blowing the zener when the load is removed.

Answer (score 0):

Vs and Vz are different voltages. Rs drops the voltage difference between those two. The current through Rs is therefore (Vs-Vz)/Rs. This is the maximum current that this sort of voltage regulator can supply to the output.